# How can we integrate FlyWire payment gateway in the .NET Core application?

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core, angular12

I have a lot of tries to integrate a payment gateway using FlyWire but I can't able to find out anything in that.
So please provide me some solutions or steps on how can I implement a payment gateway using FlyWire.

https://www.flywire.com/platform/integrations/api

Thanks

Comment: as I can see on website you can request for demo. I would suggest to get official demo from flywire guys and also you can check with them if they already support any c# client otherwise you would have to implement by your self using there APIs.

Comment: @CodingMytra Thanks for the reply. 
Have your API documentation for the FlyWire. If you have then please share with me link.

Comment: you can check it on there github page https://github.com/peertransfer